Need help figuring out why "SELECT SUSERNAME()" is the lead blocking query?
I have an application that is running on SQL Server 2019. About 80 customers are running it and only this one customer is having this issue.
Every 12-24 hours, it's locking up all users and when we investigate what we find is that what appear to be benign queries, some not even querying a table, are listed as the lead blocking query preventing multiple other queries from continuing.
For example, this query was listed as a lead blocker -
SELECT SUSER_NAME(), SUSER_ID();

This isn't even hitting a table, yet it was blocking 8 other queries and upon killing the PID, the 8 other queries then completed and things returned to normal.
It's not always the above query, we have a table that contains the filenames of various crystal reports templates, the query that blocked in this instance was
SELECT AbsoluteName 
FROM REPORT 
WHERE ReportName = 'namehere'

This query didn't even show up as an active query, just the last query that had run under the process, but again it was listed as the lead blocker that upon killing the PID, everything cleared out.
Was hoping someone may have some advice as to how a query that isn't even hitting a table is resulting in blocking?
I've done tons of searches, etc and haven't found anything yet... thanks in advance.
I've been using Activity Monitor to see the blocking queries and wait types.
Running the "blocking queries" themselves work just fine.

Presumably running in a transaction with other previous statements that acquired locks. SQL Server doesn't keep a record of the statement that caused a lock request. It just shows you what the session is currently running

You can do: dbcc opentran to see the open trans in specific database and dbcc inputbuffer(<spid>) to see the original query of a specific spid

If that PID is the lead blocker and that query is the last thing the PID ran and killing that PID unblocks all the other queries, would that PID be allowed to run another query than the one shown when right clicking and choosing Show SQL Query while it it still listed as the lead blocker?

Thank you @siggemannen , will try these next occurrence.

Sounds like some application isn't disposing their transactions and connections properly.

dbcc inputbuffer doesn't necessarily tell you the original statement in the transaction. It is entirely possible for clients to send multiple batches in the same transaction

I don't understand the "would that PID be allowed to run another query than the one shown" - but if the session is the lead blocker (and therefore not blocked) then yes it can just carry on running different queries - if the lead blocker itself ends up getting blocked then it is no longer the lead blocker (and if the blocking chain forms a circle then this is a deadlock)
